# using *ngIf "condition" in angular2

Tags: angular

I've got problem with *ngIf, when I use it, console calls       error "Object { __zone_symbol__error: Error, fileName: Getter, lineNumber: Getter, columnNumber: Getter, message: Getter, name: Getter, stack: Getter, originalStack: Getter, zoneAwareStack: Getter, toString: value(), 4 more… }"

there is code: component.html

```xml
<div *ngIf="actPage == 0" class="landing">
        <header>
            <h1>{{actPage}}</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="cards-wrap">
            <div class="cards cards--wide">
                <a class="cards__card" href="landing.html">
                    <img src="/res/images/apply-long.svg"/>
                    <h2>Click here and fill out your profile information</h2>
                    <p>To get started with your application you must complete your profile information</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

module.ts

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { StudentRegisterComponent } from './student-register.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [ StudentRegisterComponent ],
})
class MyComponentModule {}
```

and component.ts

```typescript
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RegistrationSharingData, PagesData } from '../student.data';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    selector: 'student-register',
    templateUrl: 'student-register.component.html',
    providers: [ RegistrationSharingData, PagesData ]
})
export class StudentRegisterComponent {
    actPage: number;
    service;
    pages;
    constructor( service: RegistrationSharingData, pages: PagesData){
        this.actPage = pages.getPage();
        this.service = service;
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    nameChange(str){
        this.service.setName(str);
        console.log(str);
    }

}
```

I want to add that {{actPage}} works well, please help me, problem with *ngIf persecutes me all the time, angular version: 2.4.1

Comment: have u tried it without ```pages.getPage()``` ? eg: ```this.actPage = 0```

Comment: @Dhyey ty for answer, but it didn't help me :<

Comment: If you use this means it should work this.actPage = 0 because you are assigning value directly to actpage in constructor

Comment: I know, {{actPage}} and {{this.actPage}} writes good num. I dont know why site crashes, when I use this *ngIf

Comment: can you create plunker.

Comment: Can you add BrowserModule under imports and check

Comment: @Vignesh still doesn't work, doesn't work even for *ngIf="true", but the fun thing is that I had one more *ngIf in other html, same project, and it works well...

Comment: If you remove *ngIf condition weather the html page is rendering or not

Comment: @VigneshIf I remove *ngIf condition, the html page is rendering well.

Comment: Can you add BrowserModule under imports under app.module.ts and check

Comment: @Vignesh I did it, it still doesn't work

Comment: Try this : ngOnInit() {this.actPage = 0}

Comment: Ok, I just repaired this, my project had 2 modules, which declarated the same file, thanks anyway:)